# Access to volatile register in Ada

Tags: ada, gnat

I want to write a very simple driver to initialize, write to/read from some peripherals on a microcontroller, the same way I have done it in C.
I am using as an example a GPIO peripheral to initialize, write and read.

```
GPIOA : GPIO_Register with
   Volatile,
   Address => System'To_Address (GPIOA_Base);
   pragma Import (Ada, GPIOA);
```

If I declare a list to access all the GPIOs:

```
 type GPIO_Register_ptr is access all GPIO_Register with volatile;

 Gpio_List_Pointers : array (Integer range 1 .. 8) of aliased GPIO_Register_ptr;
```

And then assign:

```
  Gpio_List_Pointers(1) := GPIOA'Access;
```

I get the error :

```
  142:29 prefix of "ACCESS" attribute must be aliased
```

Any ideas how to sort it out ?

Comment: I don’t think that `GPIO_Register_ptr` needs to be volatile or that the components of `Gpio_List_Pointers` need to be aliased.

Comment: If you don't then you get another error type of errors related to strict-type checking.

Comment: If I do it I still get the same error :  `142:29 prefix of "ACCESS" attribute must be aliased.`

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is:

declare `GPIOA` as aliased, like this:

```
GPIOA : aliased GPIO_Register
```

EDIT:

A bit longer answer:

`GPIOA` is declared like this:

```
GPIOA : aliased GPIO_Register with
   Volatile,
   Address => System'To_Address (GPIOA_Base);
```

This means that it is a **volatile object**. The **type** of the object is still `GPIO_Register`, which is **not** volatile.
So, when you do

```
 Gpio_List_Pointers(1) := GPIOA'Access;
```

The `'Access` returns an access to an object of type `GPIO_Register`, which is **not** volatile, and the compiler won't let you do that.

To make this legal, `GPIO_Register` needs to be a **volatile type**.
This is done by changing the type definition to include an aspect specification:

```
type GPIO_Register is record 
   MODER : Bits_16x2;
   IDR : Word;
   ODR : Word; 
end record
   with Volatile;
```

Now we have a **volatile type**, not just a **volatile object**

Comment: Then I get the following error:  `142:29 access to volatile object cannot yield access-to-non-volatile type `

Comment: Then you need to also make `GPIO_Register` a volatile type.

Comment: `GPIO_Register` is a platform-dependent record :   `type GPIO_Register is record
       MODER   : Bits_16x2;  
       IDR     : Word;     
       ODR     : Word;      
    end record;
`

Comment: `GPIOA` is a volatile **object**. If you want to use the `access` attribute on it, the **type** of `GPIOA` must also be volatile. Which means the type definition of `GPIO_Register` needs a volatile aspect

Comment: That's done when you declared `GPIOA: GPIO_Register with volatile, ... ` in Ada2012.

Comment: No, that just says `GPIOA` is a volatile **object**, GPIO_Register needs to be a volatile **type**

Comment: Yes. You said that. But you need to add the volatile aspect to it.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting (missing line breaks)    In my case GPIO_Register is a record:     
`type GPIO_Register is record`  
      `MODER   : Bits_16x2;` 
      `IDR     : Word;`  
      `ODR     : Word;`  
   `end record;` 

  `for GPIO_Register use record` 
      `MODER   at 0  range 0 .. 31;`  
      `IDR     at 4  range 0 .. 31;` 
      `ODR     at 8  range 0 .. 31;`  
    `end record;`

Comment: Thanks! :) I have applied the changes above for the record and it returns no errors. I'm going to build it and try on my board later.

Comment: I find that declaring `GPIO_Register` as volatile means I don’t need to declare `GPIOA` as volatile as well.